# why is long double integer limit 1288 digits long?

Tags: c++, double, overflow, long-integer

So i read that `long double` is `128bit` But look at this code

```
long double MaxLatticePaths(int xSize, int ySize)
{
    long double sumMLP = 1;
    long double halfling = xSize;
    long double halfling2 = (xSize + ySize) - xSize;
    for (int i = xSize + ySize; i > 0; i--)
    {
        sumMLP = sumMLP * (i / halfling / halfling2);
        if (halfling > 1)
        {
            halfling--;
        }
        if (halfling2 > 1)
        {
            halfling2--;
        }
    }
    return sumMLP;
}
int main()
{
    cout.precision(2000);
    cout << "\n" << MaxLatticePaths(2141, 2140) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
16315190298711506445464892598264322618004530270611808484780866384528342404142990947031068675180336432315693066114864362480616838595308779982326735844228704193859747658947455525469514212503972044689315566655370373661400711012020016116439559215383460785418453783899764258637079659818638577531691811097773176843497403749098178590357084265715939224640515837766721249964445425407422907713026146366955975530262422859128904600571726957991140807350490417141873207653107811667562463379032199939454947412011560169185406695112167355329690269203438031734174053765724124238771087854348059881325098161615945676620050984397854854452121645886626946657578990304834766661898136369869041936431091596482074847082061571981466253927611353079662496250812546118348009094113018221097833896823648389238307188213648816781186867374971727011472177232520488240752431293118492945262684802421055224211805518127741826303341935999960697567403126622636027961181349146209938242790709547705154379310869350978424238929211385961129809235418155295715641938448321789932432238943131503779648687971230484265855387248678802953305867827800519050353584130082264868408673861330156408398501291948396647365847353078278930897136242755569528982861528875154727717184788894566681318361398503312000918432261678422910400507459471524759366270976
```

Any higher than `2141, 2140` and it overflows. But how? This is like 1288 digits, `128bit` is only 38digits. Obviously there is something wrong in my code, because i wrote another simple program and assigned a larger but nowhere near this size digit and it overflowed. Can someone point out what's the bug in my code?

Comment: Most of those digits are not significant in the sense that the next representable values will  probably change most of those digits. Your number is not actually as precise as this output makes it seem.

Comment: If your `long double` is 128-bit IEEE754 value, it can hold numbers up to 4931 decimal digits.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen But how? It's only 128bit how can it hold so many decimals. If you know someplace that explains it can u give me a link?

Comment: @rustyx Then how am i getting this ouput. Also why did you say `113bits`? It's `128bits`

Comment: @pagh282 That comment is misleading. It can represent values whose decimal representation would require that many digits, but it does not store that many digits. Think of it as storing values using scientific notation. 1E5000 would need 5001 digits to be represented completely, but I just represented it with 6 characters instead in exchange for a loss of resolution.

Comment: @pagh282 Not all 128 bits will be used for the fraction (significant digits), some bits are used for sign and exponent.

Comment: @rustyx Uh, I guess I need some more vocabulary to talk about that. I meant you can store a number up to `1e4931`, while losing precision the further you go.

Comment: But wouldn't it still need the actual 5000 digits to do computations with it? Because when i print my number without the `cout.precision()` it gives `1.63152e+1288`, But when i enable cout precision, but it also prints non zero numbers well after the 38th digits, so it still does computations on it but how?

Comment: @pagh282 It would *if* mathematical operations on `double` were exact. They are not, floating point arithmetic are generally approximations. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Edit : The extra digits are artifacts of the conversion to decimal representation. It is a little bit like if you print `1/3` it can yield infinite digits. Those digits did not require individual storage in the `1/3` expression. I'm not sure of the specifics of how printing IEEE754 works, so I'm not sure exactly how those digits are generated.

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/PGjGTf) will help clear up the confusion. In the first loop [`std::nextafter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) produces the next possible value that the type can represent. Notice that most digits are changed between values. The second loop tries to demonstrate that there are no values between those steps. Adding 1 to `x` rounds to the nearest representable value, which is the value `x` already had. Since `x` is too large, `x + 1 == x` in this case. Edit : Fixed the example link.

Comment: One thing that helped me in understanding why floating points sometimes behave strangely, was finding out that 1/10 = 0.1 is not possible to represent in binary floating point. The closest representation of 0.1 in binary floating point is `0.0001100110011` (repeating infinitely) - remember that in that number, the first 0 after the decimal point represents 1/2, then next is 1/4 and so on.

Comment: Calculations with floating-point numbers are exact, but they are in the realm of floating point numbers. Floating-point numbers are not real numbers. Most of the intuition you've developed during your life about how numbers work doesn't apply to floating-point numbers. You're comfortable with the notion that 1/3 is 0, because you've been bitten by integers not being real numbers. Same thing for floating-point -- you have to deal with it on its own terms.